# how to set block hidden on 404 page (error) Drupal

Tags: drupal

How I can set block hidden on error page. 
F.e. on drupal.org/somepagethatdoesnotexist

What have I to write in "Hide on pages" section?

Comment: Do you use a node as 404 error page or the default one of Drupal ?

Comment: A I use node for 404 page

Answer (score 2):

Thanks, I found it. Just enter

```
*404*
```

in "Hide on pages" section (with asterisks)

Comment: Doesn't seem best solution for me as you can have node with id = 404.

Comment: @maciek do you have any other option about how to resolve that without the * ? i think your comment is not very helpful

Comment: @JassonRojas please see my answer below: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32861846/1161025

Answer (score 1):

You have to write `page-404` in *Hide on pages* section.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a page--404.tpl.php without the bloc's region printed

Comment: yes, but I tried to use other option - set custom page to 404 via admin

Comment: If you set 404 page from admin, it will use the page.tpl.php, so your block region will be print